# Failed building wheel for python-rtmidi

Tags: python, magenta

I'm trying to import magenta to use wavenet, however it always fails and I cannot find any useful information online.
It keeps give me this error information

```
Building wheels for collected packages: numba, python-rtmidi, llvmlite
  Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\13003\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-417gts98\numba_d67d4f03411546d299e8418ef12a08c5\setup.py", line 358, in <module>
          metadata['ext_modules'] = get_ext_modules()
        File "C:\Users\13003\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-417gts98\numba_d67d4f03411546d299e8418ef12a08c5\setup.py", line 94, in get_ext_modules
          import numpy.distutils.misc_util as np_misc
        File "D:\Anaconda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
          from . import ccompiler
        File "D:\Anaconda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 20, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils import log
        File "D:\Anaconda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\log.py", line 4, in <module>
          from distutils.log import Log as old_Log
      ImportError: cannot import name 'Log' from 'distutils.log' (D:\Anaconda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\log.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numba
  Running setup.py clean for numba
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

```
      c:\users\13003\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-417gts98\python-rtmidi_e5f4214911f54de8b049d39f4499d15a\src\RtMidi.h(48): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'exception': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-rtmidi
  Running setup.py clean for python-rtmidi
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

```
      Message: '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WINDOWS_MM__ -Isrc -ID:\\Anaconda\\envs\\venv\\include -ID:\\Anaconda\\envs\\venv\\Include /EHsc /Tpsrc\\RtMidi.cpp /Fobuild\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\\Release\\src\\RtMidi.obj /EHsc'
      Arguments: ()
      RtMidi.cpp
      c:\users\13003\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-417gts98\python-rtmidi_e5f4214911f54de8b049d39f4499d15a\src\RtMidi.h(48): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'exception': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of python-rtmidi
  Moving to d:\anaconda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\python_rtmidi-1.4.9.dist-info\
   from D:\Anaconda\envs\venv\Lib\site-packages\~ython_rtmidi-1.4.9.dist-info
  Moving to d:\anaconda\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\rtmidi\
   from D:\Anaconda\envs\venv\Lib\site-packages\~tmidi
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-rtmidi
```

I'm sure I have installed python-rtmidi, numba,llvmlite but it keeps finding them in an unexit path.
Anyone can help me out?? I really appreciate it T_T

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this environment variable first:

```
export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```

or alternatively prefix your command, e.g. change `poetry install` to:

```
SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib poetry install
```

([source](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3693#issuecomment-1321651396))